# CodeIgniter and autoloading the database library

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've got an issue connecting to the database with CodeIgniter.

In the model, if I do

```
$this->load->database();
```

then a query such as

```
$query = $this->db->get('articles', 10);
```

works and returns data. However, when I remove the load->database line and try autoloading the database library, using

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

in application/config/autoload.php, the above query fails. As it works when I explicitly load the library, it's not a problem with my database connection. I'm using CodeIgniter 2.0.2 (the current latest release).

As most of my pages use the database I'd like to autoload it to avoid having to load it anually in each model. Have I misunderstood the documentation regarding loading the database library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you able to run a simple query from a Controller? It could be you are trying to do something wacky (we don't see your whole structure, or where the files are, so I am making assumptions here).

Answer (score 7):

I know I am probably just answering a dead question but i had the same problem.

if you are using eclipse pdt or similar IDE and modified the system>core>model.php by adding some variables just before the constructor to get code completion then the autoload doesnt work

i dont know why but the fact is it doesnt work. I restored the core>model.php to original and autoload works fine. I dont get autoload now and its really a bad experience for new coder to CI.

If you have a workaround please comment so.

Comment: if this answered your question can you please accept it? It would be nice, reputation points are handy for sudden bounty questions!

Answer (score 5):

This is just an alternative if you still can't resolve the issue. Just extend the CI_Model and auto load the database library in the constructor. Then you can just make all other models inherit from that base class.

Example:

```
<?php 
    class My_Model extends CI_Model{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
             $this->load->database();
         }
     }
```

And the all others will start like :

```
  <?php
       class Some_Model extends MY_Model{}
```

This method has the other benefit that you don't have to include the loading code line in every model you create. Also you can easily push shared functionalities among models into the parent MY_Model class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works like a boss :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my database.php from my application/config/ directory

```
$active_group = 'default';   
$active_record = TRUE;        
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mydbhost';   
$db['default']['username'] = 'myusername';    
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypassword';    
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydatabase'; 
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';    
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';    
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;    
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;   
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;   
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';    
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';    
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';    
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';    
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;    
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Check yours looks like this and rerun through the user guide at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html and reread the comments in the autoload.php file in the config directory.

The relevant line in mine reads:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'session');`

You should be loading the db library like this:

`$this->load->library('database');`

Comment: I've compared them and mine is the same - the only difference is I'm not loading the form_validation library. It works if I load the db library manually, but if I have to do that in each model, then I don't see what the autoload is supposed to do...

Comment: @fishywebby You have a choice of either loading it in the Autoloader OR via $this->load-library('database'); rather than $this->load->database();

Comment: Hey @AlunR - the context needs to clarified here... fishwebby is already saying that **NEITHER** `$this->load->database()` **NOR** `$this->load->library('database')` is an option here. I am also having the same problem and we **DON'T** want to load the database manually in every model. We want to **AUTOLOAD** it from `config/autoload.php` and apparently **AUTOLOAD** is not working. **THAT'S** where the real question is. Could we get a solution to this?

Comment: Use this bit: Check yours looks like this and rerun through the user guide at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html and reread the comments in the autoload.php file in the config directory.

The relevant line in mine reads:

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'session');

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is in your `application/config/database.php` file, the following line is set to false, instead of true.

```
//['autoinit'] Whether or not to automatically initialize the database.
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
```

Everything else looks ok.

Comment: My advice would be to try a fresh install, and see if that fixes anything. Autoload the database library, and do a simple query. Any joy? You can also try setting the `threshold` for error logging to `4` in your `config.php` file and checking the logs.

Comment: Tried the fresh install, and it worked :-) Returning to my original code, I've tracked down the problem - I was using [this](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Chuck_Son%27s_take/) technique to add a header and footer to every page, and for some reason that was screwing up the autoload it seems. I'll have to look into other ways of doing the header and footer thing. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @DaveHollingworth your url is not working can you give me some other url

Comment: @FaizKhan this is quite an old post - but try this one: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-adding-header-and-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Shababhsiduque,

Just you we're right, at least in my case!

The workaround to getting the ide to work is creating the reference variables in ANOTHER CI project.

That is leave the system model as it is in the current project but modify it in another project.

Then change the php buildpath (project->properties->phpbuildpath) to the project with the variables.

Note this are settings for Aptana Studio 3.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PHP Autoload Class Magic function in this case.

```
    function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/'. $class . '.php' );
    }
}
```

This code must copied inside the **config.php** (after the last line) within Application folder.

This code will automatically load libraries for you when its needed.

It might work. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because there was another occurrence of `$autoload['libraries']` inside the same file and it reset the array.