# Codeigniter issues, w/ Database on autoload

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I am starting a new CodeIgniter project and I get a 404 error when I autoload the database class. Has anyone else run into this issue. What is the cause of it? I would appreciate any advice. Also I have started with a new project and it worked. I encountered the issue when I added database to the autoload list...

Thanks

Comment: As much probably will not have to do with the database. You could put the line you added in autoload?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); Is what I wrote in my autoload file.

Answer (score 1):

How familiar are you with arrays? in /application/config/autoload.php, your $autoload['libraries'] array should include 'database'.

If you have no other libraries autoloading, it should look like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

FYI: Please post what you've tried next time you ask a question - but welcome to SO!

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); Is what I wrote in my autoupload file.

Comment: and by autoupload I mean autoload

Comment: That's perfect! If you're getting a 404 error, it's not your config/autoload.php file that's the error. I'd suggest reinstalling CI from a completely fresh download, changing the config/autoload.php file, then copy/paste/test/rinse/repeat all your other code.

Also, you should check your application/config/routes.php & .htaccess files to make sure you're not going overboard on the redirects.

Comment: Ok I did a fresh installation and the only thing I did was autoload the database class, and I get the same result. Any more suggestions??

Comment: Ok, try this: Create 1 page with it loading manually, and 1 page with no database. If there's something wrong with the manual load, your database credentials could be wrong....

Comment: PS: Last time I had a 404 nightmare with CI it was because of my application/config/routes.php file.

Comment: I did what you said. I created one file where the database library was called manually (of course I took it out of the autoload array). I also created a controller that didnt call the db library. I could load the one with out the db lib but got the same internal server error with the one that loaded the db class. I triple checked the db creds and they are correct. I even changed the password to something simpler to make sure that I had that correct as well... What do you think?

Comment: Are you sure you're using 2.0.3? I am not sure what's wrong with your database connection - clearly it's got nothing to do with autoloading. One of the answers here has a clean config/database.php file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714823/codeigniter-and-autoloading-the-database-library