# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::get()

Tags: codeigniter

I got the error.

```
Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::get()
```

I find out to solve it but I couldn't.I already loaded database library in autoload.php .

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'Template', 'email','database');
```

Model.php

```
$query = $this->db->get('team');
```

Comment: show this **I already loaded database library in autoload.php**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter and autoloading the database library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714823/codeigniter-and-autoloading-the-database-library)

Comment: in config database.php enable `$query_builder = TRUE;`

Comment: it works. Thanks @Artier

Answer (score 0):

in config database.php enable `$query_builder = TRUE`;